# Why does Spyglass trust Lorraine?

Tags: plot-explanation, atomic-blonde

In the movie *Atomic Blonde*, most of the characters are spies for one nation or another, competing to get their hands on a list, hidden in a watch, that contains the identities of every spy in Berlin. The main character, Lorraine, arranges to smuggle the list's author, a Stasi agent called "Spyglass", to the west, with the help of her apparent partner in British Intelligence, who is called Percival. Spyglass has memorized the list and thus is a threat to multiple intelligence agencies, though

> it is the Russians and the English who eventually murder him.

In fact, Percival acquires the list himself and discovers from it that

> Lorraine, though supposedly a British agent herself, has other loyalties. She kills him to keep this secret.

If the list contains this information, and Spyglass has memorized it, why would he have trusted her?

> He knew the Russians were trying to kill him, and that she was supposedly working for the Russians.

Comment: The English don't murder Spyglass, an agent who went rogue did.

Answer (score 3):

> Spyglass has memorized it, why would he have trusted her?

The list is spy-material. It probably contains a lot of codenames (for agents, operations, ...), so a Stasi officer, who doesn't know anything about this high spy game, won't be able to understand the information presented in the list. It would need another spy to understand it. Besides, Spyglass doesn't know anything about Lorraine except of course that she is an MI6 agent and that her name is Lorraine which is **most likely** not her real name (just another codename for this mission). Percival was able to identify her because he is also an MI6 agent, so he can connect the dots and deduce that she is in fact Satchel.

**Example:** If the list says that Satchel's real name is *so-and-so* or it says that Satchel operated in some place between some date and some date, ... then Spyglass will never know that Lorraine is Satchel.